# CentOS should I use 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: centos, linux

Sorry if this is a noob question. I have just come to the choice of picking 64 or 32 bit CentOs. My processor is 64bit and I have heard 64bit can be faster and has more expansion capaability. The only issue I am worried about is software capability. I need to have FFMPEG, clam av, and x264 libraries installed. Would a 64bit installation affect the ability to run certain programs in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have a very small amount of memory or intend to run your memory at >95% all the time then you'll be fine with 64-bit and it'll scale better too :)

Comment: great, so program compatibility should be good too?

Comment: Yep, most code's available either in both 32-and-64-bit binaries or worst-comes-to-worst you can compile yourself.